# Did I make a mistake with my first binary search? what is wrong in my codes?

Tags: java, binary-search

```
public static void main(String[] args){

}
public final static int NOT_FOUND = -1;
public int binarySearch (int[] number, int searchValue){

    int     low = 0,
            high = number.length - 1,
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
    while(low <= high && number[mid] != searchValue){
        if(number[mid] < searchValue){
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid -1;
        }
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
    }
    if(low > high){
        mid = NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return mid;       
}
}
```

I made a binary search but it didn't run. what is the problem in the codes?
There is no error but when I run it theres nothing.

Comment: Post the rest of your `main()` method.

Comment: Lol if you are unsure of how to call a method that will execute when your program is ran, i don't think binary search would be the first thing to start learning.

Comment: @Brian i think that is the rest of his main method.

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr. Agreed, hence the flag as dupe of "How to call a method in Java"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call a binary search in your main.

Comment: Use the method you created and pass in your array
public static void main(String[] args){binarySearch(arrayOfNumbers, valueYou'reLookingFor);}

Comment: but how? i didnt get it. im just a beginner in programming.

Comment: like this?public static void main(String[] args){
        binarySearch(arrayOfNumbers, valueYou'reLookingFor);
    }
    public final static int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    public int binarySearch (int[] number, int searchValue){